# how to combine duplicated object in array

Tags: javascript

I got an array like this

```js
let p = [
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 33,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 55,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
]
```

I want to combine the duplicated item, and add extra `quantity` key in each object

So I will have array like this

```js
p = [
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
        quantity:2
    },
    {
        sku: 33,
        data: { name: 'so', price: 98 },
        quantity:1
    },
    {
        sku: 55,
        data: { name: 'do', price: 77 },
        quantity:1
    },
]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Arary.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over array and create a new one based on calculations like following:

```js
let p = [
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 33,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 55,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
];

var reducedArray = p.reduce((acc,item) => {
  var previousItem = acc.find(findItem => findItem.sku === item.sku);
  if(!previousItem){
    acc.push({...item, quantity: 1})
  }else{
     previousItem.quantity++
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(reducedArray);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

```js
let p = [
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 33,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 55,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
    {
        sku: 12,
        data: { name: 'pro', price: 100 },
    },
];

let result = p.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {
   
   const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.sku === currentValue.sku);
   
   if (index === -1) {
      currentValue.quantity = 1;
      arr.push(currentValue);
   } else {
       arr[index].quantity++;
   }
  
   return arr;
  }, []);
      
 console.log(result);
```